# myBatis select to existing object

Tags: mybatis

Is it possible to run a select query that updates an existing java object with myBatis.

For example given this existing java object:

```
Customer{
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

lets say I already have a Customer instance C with an Id of 1.

how can I run a myBatis select query that will update that instance rather than create a new instance.

Comment: Wouldn't any myBatis tutorial explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update the object in memory, you would have to setter each attribute of the object in memory with the result of the query.

```
Customer customer = new Customer(1,"C",null);//Object in memory
Customer customerQuery = selectQueryMyBatis(); //Query object

customer.setFirstName(customerQuery.getFirstName());
customer.setLastName(customerQuery.getLastName());
```